# how to get the last 20 days dates in the form of list in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, date, python-datetime, timedelta

how to get last `20 days` dates till `current date` using the `date` and `datetime`

Like eg CurrentDate = `2020-11-02`

i can easily get the `previous` date
Here is the code

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 1)
print(today)
print(yesterday)
```

but how do i get the last past `20 days` dates in python?

My expected output like

```
Dateslist= ['2020-10-13','2020-10-14','2020-10-15','2020-10-16','2020-10-17','2020-10-18','2020-10-19',
...., '2020-11-02']
```

Any Help would be appreciated and thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this with list comprehension

```
today = date.today()
Dateslist = [today - timedelta(days = day) for day in range(20)]
```

This will return  datime objects in case you need to use them anywhere else in the code, if you want the strings like the expected output just add `str()`

```
Dateslist = [str(today - timedelta(days = day)) for day in range(20)]
```

in case you need more advanced time formating in the string `datetime.strftime()` is worth checking

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
today = date.today()

lst = []

for x in range(20):
   lst.append(today - timedelta(days = x+1))

print(today)
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[datetime.date(2020, 11, 1), datetime.date(2020, 10, 31), datetime.date(2020, 10, 30), datetime.date(2020, 10, 29), datetime.date(2020, 10, 28), datetime.date(2020, 10, 27), datetime.date(2020, 10, 26), datetime.date(2020, 10, 25), datetime.date(2020, 10, 24), datetime.date(2020, 10, 23), datetime.date(2020, 10, 22), datetime.date(2020, 10, 21), datetime.date(2020, 10, 20), datetime.date(2020, 10, 19), datetime.date(2020, 10, 18), datetime.date(2020, 10, 17), datetime.date(2020, 10, 16), datetime.date(2020, 10, 15), datetime.date(2020, 10, 14), datetime.date(2020, 10, 13)]
```